# How to convert list(string) to Python's set format in Terraform

Tags: string, list, variables, arraylist, terraform

I would like to apply a variable as a resource's argument, using [Python's set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) format syntax of `{"element-1","element-2",...}`. A guiding principle is to let the end-user load the module and enter the details as comfortably as possible.

I've created a module with the `OPTIONAL LANGUAGES` variable:

```hcl
variable "OPTIONAL_LANGUAGES" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of ISO 639-1 two-letter language codes."
}
```

So when the end-user will use it, the module will look similar to that:

```hcl
module "my_module_instance_name" {
  source = "../modules/my_module"

  OPTIONAL_LANGUAGES = ["aa","ab","ac"]
}
```

The thing is, that in the same module, I would like to apply this variable inside a resource's argument, using the following format:
`{"aa","ab","ac"}`

Is there a more user-friendly solution than passing it as a simple string of `OPTIONAL_LANGUAGES = "{\"aa\",\"ab\",\"ac\"}"`?

Comment: What is that format `{"aa","ab","ac"}`? this is not TF valid syntax.

Comment: @Marcin It is a set of interpolated strings in Python. @ Erelphant Without the relevant Python code you are describing, it is currently unclear what you are asking. Please add details about the Python code to elaborate.

Comment: @MattSchuchard It's not Python code, rather that I used it to explain the required syntax. This is the way I need to implement an argument in a Terraform verified provider's resource.